# Defining and working with global object for codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, magento, soap

Hello I am just working with Magento Soap clinet. And I'm creating lots function inside one controller and that's why I want to set $client and $session_id as global.

Here is my code-

```
    <?php
```

// Turn off all error reporting

```
      error_reporting(0);
```

//including SOAP client

```
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/client/soap_clinet.php';
```

//class Api

```
     class Api extends CI_Controller{
```

//public variables

```
     public $variable = "tree";  //working fine
```

//Defining $client object as following also creating error.

```
      public $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/mystore/index.php/api/?wsdl');  

      public $session_id;


 public function _construct()
 {
   parent::_construct();
 }


  function index()
 {

 $data['title'] = "SOAP";
 $data['heading'] = "Showing Magento SOAP connectiviy";

  $this->load->view('apiview', $data);  
 }
```

//I need help for this function

```
  function login(){


 try{
        $this->session_id = $this->client->login(
        'fmniloy',
        'abc123'
        );

        echo 'Connection complete: session id ='.$this->session_id;
     }

  catch (SoapFault $fault)
  {
   echo 'Fault Code: '.$fault->faultcode.'<br/>';
   echo 'Fault Reason: '.$fault->faultstring;
  }


  }  //login ends


   function tree()
  {   
   //it's printing global $variable successfully

      echo $this->variable;
  }




  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Please note that I'm Codeigniter framework and SOAP client to connect with a running Magento site.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution.
First of all it's not possible to declare a object as public. We can pass $client object and $session_id to other functions. The solution is as following.

```
    <?php
```

// Turn off all error reporting
        error_reporting(0);
//including SOAP client

```
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/client/soap_clinet.php';
```

//class Api

```
       class Api extends CI_Controller{

 //public variable
      public $remote_server = "http://localhost/mystore/index.php/api/?wsdl";
      public $username = "fmniloy";
      public $password = "abc123";


         public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
         }


    function index()
   {

     $data['title'] = "SOAP";
     $data['heading'] = "Showing Magento SOAP connectiviy";

      $this->load->view('apiview', $data);  
    }


       //Login to Server
        function login(){


     //login to Client Serve
      $client = new SoapClient($this->remote_server); 

      try{
      //filled with webservice username and passwd 
         $session_id = $client->login(
         $this->username,
          $this->password
        );

        //echo 'Connection complete: session id ='.  $session_id;

        }

        catch (SoapFault $fault)
       {
           echo 'Fault Code: '.$fault->faultcode.'<br/>';
           echo 'Fault Reason: '.$fault->faultstring;
        }
```

//inputting $client object and $session_id to an array
           $soap_vars = array($client, $session_id);
//return values to use in other functions
            return $soap_vars;

```
         }
```

//login ends

```
          function tree()
          {
           $soap_vars =  $this->login();




           $result = $soap_vars[0]->call($soap_vars[1], 'catalog_category.tree');
          echo '</br></br></br>Catagory Tree: ';
         var_dump($result);

        }




    }
       ?>
```